# Are paginated comments required for publishing Themes?

Tags: theme-development, themes, comments-template

So i implemented nearly every feature into my new WordPress Theme, while checking every Imported Page / Post from the .xml Import i realized that i am missing the Paginated Comments Feature.

Is this required for theme publishing into the official repository?

*(Sorry if this Question is kinda duplicate, it's a bit hard to Google a related subject (every result is flooded with weird stuff)*

Comment: On a whim I would say yes. The [handbook](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/handbook/review/required/) mentions use of `the_comments_pagination()`. Have you used the [Theme Check plugin](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/theme-check/)?

Comment: Now i did, thanks for Sharing (I am kind a new to Wordpress), got a lot of warnings about my Composer packages, hah! BUT the Point is: It's required. thanks for helping